# AWS only whitelist IP for API-Gateway which called Route 53 or other Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I want to secure a public API. For that I would host a public Website on AWS Infastrukture and a API. The API would be available through the API Gateway. Now would be my question if there is any technical way or service to restrict access to those ip adresses which called the Website running on Lightsail/S3/EC2 or if this would be possible with the DNS-Server (Route 53)?

Thank you in advance :)

I tried to play around with whitelisting and ip restritions but there Where no 'dynamic' approach I searched for. Any ideas also other Hyperscalers are welcome.